# What is Darson's Seat Belt

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, technique

A `seat belt` is a famous and well-known back choke in BJJ. Recently, I heard that there is an additional version for this choke known as Darson's Seat Belt (most probably called by Darson Hemmings). I haven't found any sources for it. Is there an additional/ different name for this? Is there any video/ source that explain what is it and how to do it?

Comment: Seat belt isn't a choke itself, rather the default position a BJJ grappler usually assumes after taking the back, and can lead to easy choke setups

Comment: I sent a tweet to Darson. I'm hoping he can weigh in on this.